# Database migration sqlaclhemy gives an attributeError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I've build a flask application with a sqlalchemy based db. I use the migrate script from:
[Link to mega tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)
But when i run this script i get a attributeError.
here is a screenie from the error: [Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl5po.png)

Comment: You'll have to include your model definitions in the question.

Comment: From the error, it appears that in your model definition you have used a string in a place where you should have used an object.

Comment: `sqlachemy-migrate` has been replaced by [alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/). You should use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll copy nathan's answer here so i can prove it right.

sqlachemy-migrate has been replaced by alembic. You should use that instead.